# SQL statement within while loop, is there a way to increase performance?

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm very new to SQL and I implemented a SQLite database (no DMS) in one of my applications. Everything works like a charm but I have one problem in a method as stated below. This method should insert the same data into the database several times:

```
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertNewRequest)) {

            statement.setString(1, request.getDate().toString());
            statement.setString(2, request.getTime().toString());
            statement.setString(3, request.getRequestType().toString());
            statement.setString(4, request.getOperatingSystem().toString());
            statement.setString(5, request.getComment().toString());
            statement.setString(6, request.getLocation().toString());

            while (quantity > 0) {
                statement.executeUpdate();
                quantity--;
            }

}
```

Generally speaking this works but I experience a huge performance loss. As far as I know this could be because the database driver is locking and unlocking the database everytime?

So my question is:  How would an more experienced Java/Sql developer implement this method?  I could build the statement at runtime in the while loop but there I see the problem that I'm not able to prevent SQLInjection with the `setString()` method.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

As Peter Lawrey stated, SQLite is not designed for performance but for simplicity. If SQLite just needs its time then it is as it is. I just want to make sure if there's a better way to execute several identical statements at once.

This is a snapshot after the method above is executed with `quantity = 20`.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by huge performance loss? SQLite isn't designed for performance it's designed for simplicity. Have you tried profiling this to see why it is taking so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops should be avoided when working with SQL. SQL is very good in working with sets, i.e., an operation can be executed on a high number of records very efficiently. Calls to the DB operating on only one record; however, have a big overhead.

One way to deal with this problem is to have a helper table containing only numbers. For instance the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... 100. Now you can create an insert statement like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 123, "abc", "xyz"
FROM numbers
WHERE numbers.number < quantity
```

This does not really insert values from the numbers table, but only constants. The numbers table is just used for the multiplication effect.

This SQL statement can easily be parametrized and made sql injection proof.